# TypeScript Data structure for indexed actions table

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a series of roles with ascending permissions. I also have series of issue states.  I expect both of these to be represented as TypeScript enums.

I wish to provide a series of available actions, for different roles, for issues in different states:
[image]

I have a couple of related challenges.

1. I wish to have a data structure where the role/issue-state are indexed by TS enums
2. I wish to be able to store data in the structure in a legible manner (for easy review by a domain expert), like below

```
actions[engineer][newReqest] = ["Claim"]
actions[engineer][liveRequest] = ["Submit for review"]
```

3. When determining the actions for the current role ("Manager") I should be able to retrieve the inferred actions for the lower roles too ("Engineer" and "Team Lead")

Can anybody point me to the TypeScript object type that best suits the above scenario?

Comment: How about implementing BitMask ? It is a common practice to do it with help of TS enums. See typescript source code https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/main/src/compiler/checker.ts

Comment: Aah, thanks.  Yes - that would be a strategy for the "inherited permissions".  However, I "think" it prevents the indexed assignments I was hoping that the Domain Experts could review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've attempted a solution in a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=307#code/KYOwrgtgBASg9gG2AZygbwLACgpQKIgDmAliMMAE4A02uAKsAIYQAyTAJpTTlALKMhGhStgC+2bKEhQAksmRhgAZQAujFSnS0oAOWAB3brhbEAbsCNQAwgjjJg7MRKwBjOCGQqojFyuLvUAF4oAG0AXWwfPwCQuQVlNQ1kADo9fTCoYPDI338PWPlFVXUUZJNzDKyIrCi85AL44qTkmzsHStDq2pi4osTStLCQ+CQUghIySg6QgCIbRmIIGa7cnsKEkpTy4CGR0vHScgppmaUwACMIYhVlnOj83o3m7d3EUoZmNkZOY8zQmYAgi4XMAAA43KhQGYwYAAK2AvluNVWD3WTVKrXs7Feo2S-EEwl+WWhwAA8qDQEjsG4PF5uh4AGJwCh-AAUKnOCCB92QAC5vCAAJ6QzwlfmPdHISEUN78vbIACU-IBFAojEFAB5VBRSIQAHyZA2YHg0zxQABmzPRfw5XJR9VFGmquFNdPtf0tFHRyXNxAQGgorNZwCQEFAKn5AmFUFInAAHvzwBBzpQFYaYyB41ANcEZUgFdoKMAVGAKCBvPafQh1KyAExpgA+Dc6Tiw1ICb2StkIrJmH2gSG+lAtzKgCDMwBj6xmkPpyCZgbnkIl-S2E8h8uS-a+PwVBdcHaQXbgPb7TAHHGHnqgLlsWKn8RnFZ5C9ZS9kaNXLTvDg3bxS26XhQe7th4nbdr2+JCFeo63m07APooT5zq+74rps37wX+uJQYSIFtlgSBeAoEAQIwFCCn8MwzNgnqskRUCOpOpAfo0q5psauDEOarIAITEMgOiMDorIANRMXuWg8LgdEMXmzHlvKHHaLgXE8fxgnCWJ8mSZxqn6SRZEUVAonBExJlQpCMwWfJuCiZZUIWShzJvvaIr9NKbxpvZMwADogDR0mqeIQUhbgIUhaa4Enr2ZykeRgpPlC-lPoZCX7kAA).  I supports the domain-expert-legible assignment, but I have some remaining TS errors.  It could probably be improved...

```
enum Roles {
  Engineer,
  TeamLeader,
  Manager
}

enum IssueStates {
  New,
  Live,
  Closed
}

const actions = []
actions[IssueStates.New] = []
actions[IssueStates.Live] = []
actions[IssueStates.Closed] = []
actions[IssueStates.New][Roles.Engineer] = ["Claim"]
actions[IssueStates.Live][Roles.Engineer] = ["Submit"]
actions[IssueStates.Live][Roles.TeamLeader] = ["Accept", "Reject"]
actions[IssueStates.Closed][Roles.Manager] = ["ReOpen"]

const actionsFor = (tblActions: any, state: IssueStates, role: Roles): Array<String> => {
  const forState = tblActions[state]
  const actions = forState.filter((element: any, index: number) => index <= role)
  return actions.flat(2) || []
}

console.log("Team leader for live issue", actionsFor(actions, IssueStates.Live, Roles.TeamLeader))
console.log("Team leader for closed issue", actionsFor(actions, IssueStates.Closed, Roles.TeamLeader))
console.log("Manager for closed issue", actionsFor(actions, IssueStates.Closed, Roles.Manager))

let summary = ""
for(let state in IssueStates) {
  if(!isNaN(+state)) {
    for(let role in Roles) {
      if(!isNaN(+role)) {
        summary += state + ", " + role  + ", " + actionsFor(actions, state, role) + "\n"
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log("Summary",  "\n", summary)
```

Comment: I think it is better to use `actions` as an object instead of array

Comment: Thanks @captain-yossarian.  I _think_ that would prevent me using the "trick" for inherited actions - since that relies on the array counter.
Would you be interested in submitting an object-based solution as an Answer?

Comment: I still not sure about `actions` structure. Please take a look at this https://tsplay.dev/NBekdw . What about `IssueStates.Live` property? it has two values. SHould it be a tuple? I'm not sure how to express it in a way you expect

Comment: Thanks for that @captain-yossarian.  I see the structure.  It's _slightly_ less legible when assigning values, but more significantly it doesn't allow the "inherited" permissions.